# Server connection authentication error

Tags: authentication, filezilla, private-key

I use the digitalocean server and the ssh key authentication. Of late my filezilla keeps giving me authentication error. The error message is Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) Error: Could not connect to server. I have verified my private key and the location it is present in. Everything seems OK. Also I don't have passphrase protection.

My verbose log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuw1pz9twqraz0x/Screenshot%20%2839%29.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyktfj8rfo65lky/Screenshot%20%2840%29.png?dl=0

The logs stretch over the two links.

Comment: Show us complete FileZilla log file + Tell us how did you *"verified your private key"*.

Comment: I'm assuming you've made certain your settings reflect SSH2 and that your server does in fact have your key in the authorized_keys file. The next thing you could do is check the username in the filezilla session manager's settings, otherwise, there must be a typo or bug somewhere. Assuming you're using openssh server and the latest stable release of Filezilla, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I verified my private key location and also checked for typos using a text editor. My complete log file is

Comment: Status: Connecting to 139.59.78.96...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command: keyfile "C:\Codeprojs\Putty Keygen\nikiPro.ppk"
Command: open "root@139.59.78.96" 22
Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error: Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 139.59.78.96...
Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command: keyfile "C:\Codeprojs\Putty Keygen\nikiPro.ppk"
Command: open "root@139.59.78.96" 22

Comment: Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: @Dooley_labs I checked the username and made certain that the settings reflect SSH2.

Comment: Verbose log file, not the message log from GUI, please! And include it in your question. Do not post in comments, it's unreadable! + *"I verified my private key location"* - That's sooo vague! Be specific!

Comment: I apologise, extremely new to all this. Verbsose log has been displayed in the question. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Please show the screen of your connection --> SFTP settings and be sure the private key is pointed there correctly as you would expect. It looks like the key pair authentication is an issue as if it does not find the private key to match to the public upon connection. Do you control the server and the client both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed. I had an issue with the public and private keys. I had mismatched the two. They need to be used as a pair once generated.